# Detect 3 fingers touch in the whole app without affecting the subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I am making an iPad app where you can swipe/pan with 3 fingers at any time on the whole screen (cancel action)
It's working with a UISwipeGestureRecognizer or UIPanGestureRecognizer but the subviews underneath my fingers (for instance a UITableView or UIScrollview) received the touch and moves. Which I don't want.

My idea was to put a transparent UIView on top of the whole app that will forward touches to the other views or not. I tried something with hitTest but I think I didn't understand it well since the return number of touches isn't right and takes time...

Thanks a lot if you can help me with that :)

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
        if (event.allTouches.count >= 2) {
            return self;
        }
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use the

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

delegate of UIGestureRecognizer to define which gestures is valid in the same time.

E.g:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

    NSLog(@"gestRecogn: %@ otherGestRec: %@",[[gestureRecognizer class] className],[[otherGestureRecognizer class] className]);

    if ([[[gestureRecognizer class] className] isEqualToString:@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer"] && [[[otherGestureRecognizer class] className] isEqualToString:@"UILongPressGestureRecognizer"]) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ([[[gestureRecognizer class] className] isEqualToString:@"UILongPressGestureRecognizer"] && [[[otherGestureRecognizer class] className] isEqualToString:@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer"]) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```